# Program with while 1 hogs the processor

Tags: c, linux, while-loop

I am currently experimenting to find out why a process with while 1 hogs the processor. Here is the sample of my code.

```
int *a = NULL;
while(1)
{
    a = (int*)malloc(10000);
    std::cout << "Ptr to allocated memory: " << a << std::endl;
}
```

When I run the "top" command, it is at the top as long as it is executing. Can someone please help me understand the reason? If someone with assembly level knowledge could also provide an answer it would be really nice.

Comment: Do you give it room to breathe, what do you expect?

Comment: What else you expect this code to do? Normally when code runs it uses CPU... when it wait it does not use CPU... Your code *does not wait* for anything...

Comment: I understand that. What happens inside the system. WHY can it not allow another process to execute. There must be some reason.

Comment: Beware the OOM Killer!  Eventually, it will strike.  Especially if you actually try to access the allocated memory. Also, it is an odd C program that uses `std::cout` and related constructs.  However, the answer is much the same.

Comment: Other processes will be executed when (a) they're ready, and (b) the scheduler says it is their turn.  But your `while (1)` loop is likely to be ready more often than other processes.

Comment: Actually, I would expect this code to get blocked on output much of the time, (at least up until such time as the continual malloc-with-no-free calls fail).

Answer (score 2):

`while(1)` will run something forever (or until there is a `break`). The code inside the loop will be executed constantly, hogging much of the processor.

This is like a parent with a very needy child- your program will get all of the attention, without letting any of the other programs get what they need.

Comment: Okay so what this means is that the OS will only store the context of the process in the PCB and allow a new process to execute when there is some "break" in this process. Am I right?

Comment: @ParthShah: On Linux, excluding real-time threads, no. The scheduler will decide the process has consumed more than its fair share of CPU time and pre-emptively switch to some other process (if there are any other processes to switch to).